# Update a local db table from remote SQL Server db table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, ssms, remote-server, data-synchronization

I would like to have a **local copy of a remote db table, updated every N minutes**. How can I accomplish this with sql management studio (possibly) without build a script from myself?

*This is the table*

[image]

Comment: Please add some sample data, have u tried `merge` scripts to accomplish this task

Comment: @BHouse The table I would like to synchronize in my local server is very simple: I've updated the question. No, I haven't tried merge scripts yet: now I'll read about it

Comment: 'Merge` procs are quite handy if u have linked server connection established, read my post about `merge`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306187/ssis-reading-from-record-set-instead-of-database/47306885#47306885

Comment: Use Import-Export wizard to import data first time. On the last step of wizard save SSIS package. Create a job which will use this package every n minutes.

Comment: @gofr1 what happens if there is update on remote table for float columns instead  of insert with import/export wizard ?

Comment: @BHouse that is the way, but OP clearly wants to accomplish this _without build a script from myself_. With import-export there is no need in writing scripts.

Comment: @gofr1 I've created the SSIS package, it works the first time BUT at the second run it gives errors on primary keys, obviously: how can I import only new data?

Comment: @MassimoVariolo run wizard one more time. Now choose "Append rows to the destination table" or "Delete rows in destination table". Save package with same name (rewrite it).

Comment: @MassimoVariolo More info on this one can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/column-mappings-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)

Comment: @MassimoVariolo if u do not want to script anything  in ssms, use look up transformation in ssis. I strongly believe you can achieve this better with a proc, i can help to write if u like

Comment: @gofr1 append does not append ony new lines :( and delete not an option for me. I'll go with a procedure ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql server import and export wizard seems to be not the right way for me: infact it does not support the import from a table to another of only new content.

I wrote a simple procedure, for syncing a local table with a remote one, with only new data, depending on timestamp

```
create procedure p_sync_from_remote
as
begin
    declare @lastitem Datetime = 
         (select top 1 Time_Stamp from table_destination order by Time_Stamp desc)
    if (@lastitem is null) or (len(@lastitem) <= 0)
    begin
        insert into table_destination
        select * from table_source
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into table_destination
        select * from table_source where Time_Stamp > @lastitem
    end
end

exec p_sync_from_remote
```